# Reorder a List and Find All Possible Combinations

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, combinations

I have a Python list with a variable number of elements.

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
```

I need to rearrange these elements inside the list and find all possible unique combinations.

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
[d,b,a,e,c]
[e,d,a,c,b], etc.
```

I cannot have same elements repeated, or have any elements removed:

```
[a,a,a,d,e]  <-- bad
```

Comment: OK. Now, what have you tried to solve this, and can you show your code and explain what difficulties you are facing in your implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `itertools.permutations`, for example:

```
import itertools
my_list = [a, b, c, d]
for x in itertools.permutations(my_list):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)`([a,b,c,d,e])`.